# java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to get Data between fragments in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to develop an android application that depends on a web service and I'm using fragments to get my app to run in mobile and tablet ..

this is the activity that holds fragments in both modes and check which mode
then define the onItemClickListener depending in which mode, details are displayed in a DetailFragment (Landscape) or an DetailActivity (Portrait)

```
public class AppelsFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

    public static List<Appel> appels = null;
    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listAppels);

        if (this.mListView != null) {
            this.mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            this.mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }

        // this is an asynctask that retreive data from RestAPI and set the Adapter for my listview
        new Appels().execute();


        View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);


        mDualPane = detailsFrame != null
                && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }

        if (mDualPane) {

            showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
        } else {
            mListView.setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {

        showDetails(position);
    }


    void showDetails(int index) {
        mCurCheckPosition = index;

        if (mDualPane) {

            mListView.setItemChecked(index, true);

            DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.details);
            if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {

                details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }

        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("index", index);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

class Appels extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Appel>> {
..... }
}
```

the problem I face is a NullPointerException in the DetailFragment, in the Portrait mode I have no problem

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.marocbusiness11.app/com.mycompany.marocbusiness11.app.FragmentLayout}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mycompany.marocbusiness11.app.DetailsFragment.onCreateView(DetailsFragment.java:42)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

this is the code of the DetailFragment

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(container == null)
            return null;

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details,container,false);
        TextView txtAffichage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAffichage);
        txtAffichage.setText(AppelsFragment.appels.get(getShownIndex()).getNumOrdre().toString());

        return v;

    }
}
```

the problem triggered by this instruction

```
txtAffichage.setText(AppelsFragment.appels.get(getShownIndex()).getNumOrdre().toString());
```

I think the way I defined my List that is

```
public static List<Appel> appels = null;
```

might be the cause of this problem, if there is any suggestions of how I can handle it
Or what I should change

**Thanks in Advance**

/////// Post Edited

in the portrait mode I'm using DetailsActivity that instantiate the DetailsFragment so it's always about the Fragment ..

this is the code of the DetailsActivity

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            finish();
            return;
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();

            details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

and the details.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAffichage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited my post to add some codes, but after some research ([here](http://neilgoodman.net/2011/12/26/modern-techniques-for-implementing-rest-clients-on-android-4-0-and-below-part-1/) and [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) ) and correct me if I'm mistaken .. the problem in my asyncTask related to the fragment, the asnycTask is responsible of getting data from my Rest API as List, that list the the one I'm trying to display and work with in my fragments, the asyncTask due to connexion and quality of the network can't retreive data before the fragment try to display them ..

when this instruction is triggered

```
TextView txtAffichage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAffichage);
        txtAffichage.setText(AppelsFragment.appels.get(getShownIndex()).getNumOrdre().toString());
```

the List appels is still empty and from there the exception NullPointerException ..

I think Loaders is the solution to this, correct me if it's not ..

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
TextView txtAffichage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAffichage);
```

is probably returning `null`. Make sure `R.id.txtAffichage` is valid in both versions (portrait and landscape) of your layout resource file.